# SupportMapFragment crashes with NullPointerException on Android 4.1+

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_map_google_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/fragments_map_google"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="ru.my_app.TransparentSupportMapFragment" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and class:

```
public class TransparentSupportMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

public TransparentSupportMapFragment() {
    // SupportMapFragment sp;
    super();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup view, Bundle savedInstance) {

    View layout = super.onCreateView(inflater, view, savedInstance);
    FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
    frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    ((ViewGroup) layout).addView(frameLayout, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    return layout;
}
```

}

And in my `SherlockFragmentActivity` i'm trying to take map fragment:

```
map = ((TransparentSupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById((R.id.fragments_map_google))).getMap();
```

This code works fine on 2.3, HTS One S with 4.0 and other divices. But on Samsung Galaxy S III with 4.1.4 or Sonu Xperia Z with 4.1.2 `map` is null.

Can you tell me why? =/

Comment: A GoogleMap can only be acquired using getMap() when the underlying maps system is loaded and the underlying view in the fragment exists. This class automatically initializes the maps system and the view; however you cannot be guaranteed when it will be ready because this depends on the availability of the Google Play services APK. If a GoogleMap is not available, getMap() will return null. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment

Comment: @twntee i use getMap() in onCreate() method of my fragment. So...how can i avoid this null problem?

Comment: Not precisely your answer, but what I do it, I extend the `Fragment` class, add the `SupportMapFragment` to my fragment layout xml and then I get it in the onCreateView of Fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was cause i have old version of Google Play Services on device. Just updated it, and now map works fine.